# Multiple method calls in a request

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

i am working on a struts code wherein , there is a jsp page , pagination is done in it for records that go upto few pages.

I wont be able to post code here as its companies secured data

Problem - When i navigate from a page to next page ,at backend , on click on forward arrow , **3 methods** are called. Each page has **2 tables** . 1st table is static , will remain consistent through all the pages . 2nd table is containing the list of records for which pagination is done.

2nd table has a column for writing down any notes for that particular record. On click of the notes , a new jsp window is opened, when thats closed and i try to navigate to next page , 500 error occurs

I assume its because of losing the table values each time notes window is opened and closed as the session is not maintained. **Please let me know if my assumption is correct.**

Then i tried retaining the values by storing them in session in the method which is called in backened when notes is clicked. Now i fetched the session values in the 1st method of flow. so when forward arrow is clicked, then the 3 methods are called in sequence -> **1st method calling 2nd -> 2nd calling 3rd**. So in this process , i fetched the values only in 1st method , and not in 2nd and 3rd. Then how when after the execution of all 3 methods , next page gets loaded, it is retaining the data which was earlier missing.

In short my question is , storing values in session somewhere , then fetching it in 1st method of flow , but those values getting retained till the end of flow without actually fetching and storing them in the other 2 methods of the flow. **How are values getting retained ?**

Sorry for all the theory and no code. But i dont have permission to copy code anywhere.

Thanks in advance 
cheers :)

Comment: There's no way to know if your assumption is correct. Browser session handling re: new windows used to be browser-specific; I don't know if it still is. E.g., under Chrome, if I open a new SO window, it's the same session. The way to explain via code is to create a minimal working example--this seems like a simple matter of some data, a cpl JSPs, and some actions--it's likely hte existing code could be stripped of unrelated code and anonymized.

Comment: so you are saying that the values are getting retained from 1st method to 3rd method as they may be in same session ?